# C# Duda Basica de WPF

Tags: wpf

Estoy empezando a estudiar **WPF** y tengo una gran duda

mi proyecto **WPF** tiene  una clase Libros,la cual tiene varios atributos,pongamos de ejemplo

```
class libros
{
string atributo1;
string atributo2;
string atributo3;
}
```

pregunta 1 -para crear un objeto tipo libro o sea, hacer una instancia de esta clase,donde debo hacerlo?

> ej> libros libro1 = new libros();

cuando trabajaba en consola lo hacia en el **Main()**,pero ahora no se donde es , y no creo que sea en **MainWindow** que es la ventana que crea por defecto el programa

ya he tratado de inicial izar los objetos en **MainWindow.xaml** de mi proyecto **wpf** , pero los objetos tipo "libros" que creo solo los ve el bloque de **MainWindow** como es lógico,

si alguien pudiera ayudarme con la logica de inicializacion en WPF o darmealguna referencia de una web que pudiera ayudarme, muchas gracias de antemano y disculpen si tengo algo mal en la redaccion.

editado> codigo

public MainWindow()
        {

```
        Libros Libro0 = new Libros();

             Libro0.Identificador = 000000;
             Libro0.Titulo = "La metamorfosis";
             Libro0.Autor = "Frank Kafka";
             Libro0.Editorial = "Tupe";
             Libro0.Materia = "Ficcion";
             Libro0.CantidadEjemplares = 5;
             Libro0.Estado = true;

        label1.Content= Libro0.Autor; //exception nullreference
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: El codigo es el mismo. el lenguaje el mismo, solo que ahora tenes una vista... lo tenes que inicializar donde corresponda y moverlo segun corresponda y lo necesites...

Comment: cree un label y quiero ponerle como texto este valor >
            label1.Content= Libro0.Autor;
estoy en el mismo bloque donde inicialize Libro0 que es un objeto de tipo Libros

Comment: a que te referis? hace un [mcve] para que podamos trabajar sobre algo.. el tema no es largo, pero en el aire por ahi es dificil de explicar. sigue siendo el mismo programa.. solo que ahora tenes mas clases, inclusive las ventanas, que son otras clases... tu main lo unico que hace es levantar la primer ventana...

Comment: ok, voy a editar mi pregunta y a poner el resto del codigo ,  a ver si puedes ayudarme mas, muchas gracias

Comment: ok. con ese codigo no hacemos mucho. Libro esta definido dentro del ambito de esa funcion. No viste sobre ambito de variables? si no es asi, tenes que leer sobre eso primero. Mainwindow es una clase. Y como toda clase lo que se define en ella vive solo dentro de ella. Lo que se define en un procedimiento vive dentro del procedimiento.

Comment: a ver, tengo una Clase llama Libros, en la clase MainWindow creo un Objeto tipo Libros llamado Libro0 y le llene sus parametros, lo que no entiendo es si label1.content es de tipo string, y Libro0.autor tambien es de tipo string, por que label1.content no toma el valor de Libro0.autor y lo muestra al correr el programa , por que me esta dando error???

Comment: Que error? Deberias revisar algun tutorial de wpf para entender qie tenes que cambiar el concepto de como ves las cosas.

Comment: lanza una excepcion de system.NullReferenceException señalada en la linea de label1.content = libro0.autor;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HODOR, como va.
Te recomiendo que sigas la documentación oficial de Microsoft.-
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms752299(v=vs.100).aspx algo en español.
Por otra parte, de consola a wpf me parece algo brusco, podrías investigar sobre windows forms con lo cual vas a poder llevarte varios conceptos a wpf.

En cuanto a tu pregunta 
1)La clase la instancias cuando la necesites :>

y con el codigo

```
public MainWindow() {

        Libros Libro0 = new Libros();

             Libro0.Identificador = 000000;
             Libro0.Titulo = "La metamorfosis";
             Libro0.Autor = "Frank Kafka";
             Libro0.Editorial = "Tupe";
             Libro0.Materia = "Ficcion";
             Libro0.CantidadEjemplares = 5;
             Libro0.Estado = true;
//Asigna el valor cuando se inicialicen los elementos de window
 InitializeComponent();
        label1.Content= Libro0.Autor; //exception nullreference

    }
```

Comment: gracias, el error lo daba por que el >  label1.Content= Libro0.Autor; estaba antes del InitializeComponent,